# Como resolver o erro adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

Tags: android, android-studio, avd

Estou tendo o erro:

> Unable to run 'adb': null
>   16:08 'C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\PI\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

Ao pressionar o botão run o Android Studio não mostra nenhum dispositivo, nem os AVDs que tenho.

Ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei no Google e várias vezes encontrei que tem que fechar o processo **adb.exe**, vou lá e fecho e não resolve.

Vi também que abrir o cmd na pasta platform-tools e encerrar o server mas quando faço isso o cmd quebra a linha e o cursor só fica piscando e não faz nada.

Comment: Aq no meu eu só encerrei o adb.exe e cliquei em debug após apertar algumas vezes em restart ele funcionou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já resolvi o erro.
Havia um determinado serviço (traccar) que estava em execução no meu PC.
Só tive que reiniciá-lo e encerrar os processos **adb.exe**, e o Android Studio voltou a funcionar normalmente.
Outros dias, acontecia o mesmo, apenas tenho que reiniciar o serviço e encerrar os processos **adb.exe**.